# Debug error before main() using GDB

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, shared-libraries

Is there anyway to debug a link error or any kind of error that may occur before the execution of the main() function using GDB?

Comment: How would you expect to debug a *link* error?

Comment: What kind of error? Software exception? Hardware exception? Returned error code?

Comment: Use valgrind before gdb

Comment: Errors occuring during static intialization can be debugged.

Comment: Also you can try to set a breakpoint on _start function, that is an entry point of a binary, and have some fun with asm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway to debug a link error

Presumably you are asking about runtime link error (e.g. `error: libfoo.so: no such file or directory'), and not about (static) link step of your build process.

The trick is to set a breakpoint on `exit` or (`exit_group` on Linux) system call with e.g. `catch syscall exit`. You will then be stopped inside `ld.so` at the point where it gives up running your binary.

> or any kind of error that may occur before the execution of the main() function using GDB?

Any other kind of error, e.g. `SIGSEGV` can be debugged "normally" -- for signal you don't need to do anything at all -- GDB will just stop. For other errors, just set a breakpoint as usual.

Answer (score 1):

On way to debug initialization code (even if you don't have symbols) goes like this:

```
gdb somebinary
```

GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
etc.

```
info file
```

> Symbols from "somebinary".
>
> Local exec file:
>
> `/somebinary', file type elf64-x86-64.
>
> Entry point: 0x4045a4, etc.

```
break *0x4045a4
run
```

> ...Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004045a4 in ?? ()

From here on you can proceed as usual.

Comment: This is not working for me. I just add a bp in the same way you described, but I'm still getting the following error:
binary_file_name: error while loading shared libraries: .1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: This probably means one of dynamic libraries is missing. Try this: "LD_DEBUG=all binary_file" and see what this tells you.