# What things can cause GDB to error before hitting main?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a program with a large codebase, so I can't share a minimal example. What I've done is removed everything from `main` so that it looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm still including all of the header that I was including before. When I run the debugger (GDB 9.2) it breaks before hitting main (I've a breakpoint set on the `std::cout`) with the following:

```
Starting debugger: C:\GameDev\Tools\MSYS2-32\mingw32\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/GameDev/Colony/bin/Colony.exe
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 9.2
Child process PID: 6840
In ?? () ()
```

Which I understand means something has happened during initialisation? I looked at this question [Debug error before main() using GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149058/debug-error-before-main-using-gdb) and did as suggested, printed the info file `info file` and set a breakpoint manually on the entry point and running it again. That doesn't seem to give me any additional info (same as above); or maybe I don't know what I'm looking for and how to retrieve it.

I've tried running the program through Dr Memory but it seems to execute okay in there, up until shutdown at which point after leaving Dr Memory gives me no errors but 2 suspected false positives. Both of these look like they're pointing to MingW hashtable code, which I believe is from my use of `std::unordered_map` in a few places (the only place where that hashtable code would come in). But none of that code is invoked because `main` is effectively empty.

None of that code is statically initialised either.

So, what sort of things can cause this error? I can try and track down the offending code if I know what can do it.

Comment: Consider the case of a global variable that has complicated initialization  such as `int x = horribly_complicated_function();` or `class_with_nasty_default_constructor y;`

Comment: Consider compiling your code with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) and friends turned on.

Comment: I also see weird stuff in gdb if I place a breakpoint on the closing brace in `main`.

Comment: The first place to start is "are you building a debug build" imo.

Comment: @Taekahn yeah it's compiled with debug symbols

Comment: Have you tried removing the headers. Does it work?